# Read an Excel file (saved in several blobs) sequentially into one InputStream

Tags: java, sql, excel, hibernate, memory

I need to process big `Excel` files. My problem is `heap space` especially with `XLS` format. Even if I have one `Apsose LighCells` API to parse it sequentially I need to retrieve the file from the database in chuncks.

So far I have the file in the database in chunks of 40kb. I have an `Import` table (storing general information related to the import, for instance start and end time, data type etc.) and an `ImportData` table (containing the chunks of data as blobs). I have a one to many relation between `Import` and `ImportData`:

```
<hibernate-mapping>   <class name="com.company.import.pojos.Import
table="IMPORT_TABLE">
    <id name="id" type="integer">
      <column name="ID" />
      <generator class="some.id.generator.IdGenerator"></generator>
    </id>

    <property name="startTime" type="timestamp">
      <column name="START" />
    </property>

    <property name="endTime" type="timestamp">
      <column name="END" />
    </property>

    <property lazy="false" name="datatzpe" type="com.company.import.enums.ImportDataType">
      <column name="DATATYPE" />
    </property>

    <bag name="importDataList" table="IMPORT_DATA" lazy="true" cascade="all" inverse="false">
      <key column="IMPORT_TABLE_ID"/>
      <one-to-many class="com.company.import.pojos.ImportData"/>
    </bag>

  </class> </hibernate-mapping>


<hibernate-mapping>   <class
name="com.company.import.pojos.ImportData" table="IMPORT_DATA">

    <id name="id" type="integer">
      <column name="ID" />
      <generator class="some.id.generator.IdGenerator"></generator>
    </id>

    <property name="importTableID" type="integer">
      <column name="IMPORT_TABLE_ID" />
    </property>

    <property name="data" type="binary">
      <column name="DATA" />
    </property>

    <property name="order" type="integer">
      <column name="ORDER" />
    </property>   </class> </hibernate-mapping>
```

I use `Hibernate (4.2.3.Final)`, but even `lazy loading` in not an option because then I will have the whole list of `ImportData` objects in memory which is why I get an OutOfMemoryError and I want to avoid that.

Providing more memory is not an option (the application runs ona container that runs other applications as well, and several users might process files at the same time so the heaps space problem will eventually happen), therefore I am looking for a way to always read the next chunk of data and provide it to the stream that is given to the `Aspose API`.

I create my workbook in Aspose simply like this:

```
InputStream inStream = ....;// get the input stream somehow
Workbook workbook = new Workbook(inStream);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to implement your own InputStream, which handles multiple IS as one, handling that when you reach the end of one IS you close it and pick the next one to fill the rest of the read buffer.

I do not know any implementation for this behaviour.

How big is your file ?

Comment: We would like to support at least 100 MB files (XLS and XLSX format as well). The XLS format is harder to process sequentially, I do not know whether `Aspose` can do that or not. Right now I am tryin to feed the processing API with an `InputStream` that can handle several blobs.